# Schema capitalization(uppercase) problem when reading with Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-jdbc

Using Scala here:

```
Val df = spark.read.format("jdbc").
  option("url", "<host url>").
  option("dbtable", "UPPERCASE_SCHEMA.table_name").
  option("user", "postgres").
  option("password", "<password>").
  option("numPartitions", 50).
  option("fetchsize", 20).
  load()
```

The database I'm using the above code to call from has many schemas and they are all in uppercase letters (UPPERCASE_SCHEMA).

No matter how I try to denote that the schema is in all caps, Spark converts it to lowercase which fails to initialize with the actual DB.

I've tried making it a variable and explicitly denoting it is all uppercase, etc. in multiple languages, but no luck.

Would anyone know a workaround?

When I went into the actual DB (Postgres) and temporarily changed the schema to all lowercase, it worked absolutely fine.

Comment: Try setting `spark.sql.caseSensitive` to true when creating the Spark session. It should preserve the case.

Comment: Worked really well. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set `spark.sql.caseSensitive` to `true` (`false` by default)

```
spark.conf.set('spark.sql.caseSensitive', true)
```

You can see in the source code its definition:
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/internal/SQLConf.scala#L833

In addition, you can see in the `JDBCWriteSuite` how it affects the JDBC connector:
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/ee95ec35b4f711fada4b62bc27281252850bb475/sql/core/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/jdbc/JDBCWriteSuite.scala

Comment: Worked a charm. Thank you Spark Wizard!!!!!!!!!!!!!